# Do I need to use apostrophe after this noun in the sentence?

Tags: gerunds, apostrophe

Do I need to use apostrophe after *organizations* in the following long sentence?

> This sensitive situation has resulted in many **organizations** reviewing their business priorities as well as their strategic perspectives and putting their emphasis on consistency and conformity with business environment changes as well as quick response to market and customer needs.

By the way I am not sure if *reviewing* in the above sentence is a gerund or acting as a description phrase. What about the apostrophe if we do/don't consider *reviewing* as a gerund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ***don't need*** an apostrophe there.

That's because the 'reviewing' is not in possession of those organizations. The apostrophe is required in a sentence like this...

> An organization's goal *(for singular)* 
>  Organizations' goals to make profit in the year of 2015 *(plural, more than one organization)*

And,

*reviewing* is a *'verb'* there *(Organizations reviewing their business priorities)*. Do you see the hint? The conjunction 'and' joins the verb 'putting'.